# How to implement Schedule local notifications of React native push notification in react native

Tags: react-native, push-notification

I am using react-native-push-notifications npm library to implement notifications feature in my app. However, I want to schedule the notifications before 5 miniutes  at specific time and I am using PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule so how to implement this pls help , thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

This code is scheduling a notification for 5 minutes before 4:00 PM, 21st January 2023.

```
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notifications'

const time = new Date(2023, 1, 21, 16, 0, 0)
const fiveMinutesBefore = new Date(time.getTime() - 5 * 60 * 1000)

PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
  message: "Notification message",
  date: fiveMinutesBefore,
  repeatType: 'minute',
  repeatTime: 5,
  number: 1,
});
```

Comment: And how to know weather is AM or PM ..? pls reply if you have any idea?

Comment: const handleScheduleNotification = (title, message) => { 
createChannel();
const time = new Date(2023, 1, 22, 20, 0, 0)
const fiveMinutesBefore = new Date(time.getTime() - 5 * 60 * 1000)
  PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
    channelId: "specialid",
    title: title,
    message: message,
    date: fiveMinutesBefore,
    color: "blue",
    repeatType: 'minute',
     repeatTime: 1,
  });
};

Comment: I implement  notification for 5 miniutes before 8 but not display i try to many times with different time but not trigger notification what is wrong?  in above code pls help ...